# Оптимальное хранение условных данных в массиве

Tags: c++

Задача в том, чтобы эффективно распределить память для хранения большого количества данных (порядка десятков миллионов записей).

Существует массив записей в куче. Каждая запись хранит идентификатор типа (например 0-256). Если идентификатор имеет значение в некотором диапазоне (например 16-32), то к этой записи, по мимо идентификатора, должны прилогаться и некоторые данные каким либо способом (указатели, ссылки, параметры класса), различные, в зависимости от идентификатора.

Вопрос: какую структуру стоит реализовать для эффективного использования памяти так, чтобы не хранить лишние указатели (в том числе и nullptr) в записях, чьи идентификаторы типа не входят в диапазон 16-32, а так же для хранения различных данных, входящих в этот диапазон?

Уточнение: vector и т.д. не используются - только массивы.

Уточнение(2): порядок карточек важен, так как на самом деле это их координаты.

Comment: Разбить на два массива - с данными и без?

Comment: Уточнение: порядок карточек важен, так как на самом деле это их координаты.

Comment: Кроме идентификатора типа - других постоянных полей в структуре нет?

Comment: Верно, других постоянных полей в структуре записи нет.

Comment: Что вы собираетесь делать с этим массивом? Без списка операций над структурой данных нельзя ничего подсказать.

Comment: Алгоритм будет совершать последовательное чтение, совершая то или иное действие над средой в зависимости от прочитанной записи.

Comment: Union не подходит, так как тогда записи будут занимать слишком много места, что уже не отвечает требованию оптимального использования памяти.

Comment: Если чтение только последовательное, то переменная длина записи - вполне подойдёт.

Comment: Да, но как сделать переменную длинную записи, учитывая, что дополнительными данными может быть любой тип данных, класс или структура?

Comment: *(union)* тогда массив указателей на разные элементы объектов виртуального класса. `A <- C -> B` {C * [ ] ; A [ ] ; B [ ] ; }

Comment: Хм... Это неплохое решение, но юнионы всегда занимают одинаковое количество памяти. Я понимаю, что теперь оно значительно меньше, так как теперь в юнионе только идентификатор и указатель, но тогда те записи, у которых нет дополнительных данных все еще будут занимать место под указатель. Это неплохой вариант и я его использую, если не сможем придумать ничего другого.

Comment: Байт или два на тип записи. Если тип в нужном диапазоне - ещё указатель на данные.

Comment: `без union`. А оставить указатель плюс идентификатор типа. Виртуальность можно убрать. Это занимает много памяти.

Comment: `class C ; class A : public C ;` и т. д. `A a ; C * cp = & a ;`

Comment: Указателю тоже нужен тип данных, который в зависимости от идентификатора может отличаться.

Comment: Буду рад увидеть пример без виртуальности и пустого места под указатель у тех записей, где идентификатор вне диапазона.

Comment: Ну, если я верно понял, у вас, грубо говоря, 255 разных типов? Значит, 255 разных структур, первым байтом в которых идентификатор. И массив байтов. Считали первый байт, определили тип, отображаем на массив и работаем с ним. Все равно ведь типы вы должны знать еще во время компиляции. Единственное — не уверен, как с выравниванием, не будет ли тут проблем и не надо ли крутиться как-то хитро.

Comment: Проблем с выравниванием быть не должно, данный метод применяется в сетевых протоколах, что намекает на его актуальность.

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class Card{
public:
    int id;
};

class BigCard : public Card{
public:
    int data;
};

int main() {
    BigCard a;
    a.id = 17;
    a.data = 112;
    Card* b = &a;
    Card* c = new Card();
    c->id = 33;
    cout << ((BigCard*)b)->data << endl;
    cout << c->id << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Дальше можно создавать массив указателей класса Card, а к карточкам обращаться по приведению.

Данное решение все еще создает ссылку для каждой записи, что отвечает на поставленный вопрос лишь частично.

Comment: Получается всегда придётся хранить идентификатор и указатель. Ну или же полностью менять структуру и хранить все данные в виде массива байтов, где первые 1-2 байта будут хранить тип, а следовательно и назначение последующих байтов (данные ли они, или начало следующей записи)